# Why do I have to call an XML element in function and not in onCreate?

Tags: java, android

Full code of onCreate is here:

```
//Global variables
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
int expandedGroup = -1;
boolean notification;
boolean vibrate;
String ringtone;
int hour;
int minutes;
int day;

//UI elementi
TextView dan;
TextView ura;
ImageView facebook;
ImageView twitter;
TextView tw1, tw2, tw3, tw4, tw5, tw6, tw7, tw8, tw9, tw10, tw11, tw12, tw13, tw14, tw15, tw16, tw17, tw18, tw19, tw20, tw21, tw22, tw23, tw24, tw25, tw26, tw27, tw28, tw29, tw30;
Button nadomescanja;

//Mapa aplikacije
public static File appDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/com.whizzapps.stpsurniki/");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Mapa aplikacije se naredi, če ne obstaja
    if (!appDir.exists())
    {
        appDir.mkdirs();
    }

    //Povezava z elementi iz navigacije
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    dan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dan);
    ura = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ura);
    tw15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebook);
    twitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.twitter);

    //Nastavitev glave in noge
    View headerView = ((LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
    expListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    expListView.addFooterView(footerView);

    //Nastavitev ExpandableListView adapterja
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    //Klicanje pomembnih funkcij
    nadomescanjaClickListener();
    setCustomFontToAllTextViews();
    loadRandomQuote();
    getDay();
    getTime();
    expListViewClickListeners();
    posodabljanjeUre();
}
```

So as you can see, before the onCreate method i declare the global variables and then in onCreate instantiate those variables. Then a few lines after that I call all the methods that I need to execute in onCreate. But those methods then crash the app because of nullpointerexception (they don't get the variable yet). But if I **delete** those variables in onCreate and instantiate them in the method itself then it works.

I can't post the logcat at the moment because I'm not at home but I can let you know that it's a simple nullpointerexception error becuase it doesn't get those variables that I have set in onCreate.

Comment: Post your logcat so that we can help you

Comment: function meaning where? can you post the activity code full

Comment: Your question is not clear even code also. Please post whole code in proper flow and clear you question. @Matthew

Comment: What do you mean by this `The app crashes because of NULLpointerexception. And if I move those facebook and twitter variable declarations in to the function it works fine.`?

Comment: I updated the question, added full clode of onCreate.

Comment: are ids R.id.twitter and R.id.facebook part of your activity_main layout?

Comment: No, they are a part of footer layout for expandableListView @GopalRao

Comment: @Matthew check my edited answer... and let me know still problem exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook and twitter ImageView are not part of your Activity layout until they are added. so findViewById() will return `null` before your Views are added. search for the twitter and facebook Views after adding footerView to the expandableListView.

```
expListView.addFooterView(footerView);
facebook = (ImageView)footerView.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
twitter = (ImageView)footerView.findViewById(R.id.twitter);
```

Comment: I already do write it like this. Check the code that I have posted in my question. I posted the full onCreate.